# Not able to login mobile meteorjs

Tags: meteor

I have built an application with facebook, twitter and gplus login (using accounts-google, accounts-facebook and accounts-twitter packages) which is running fine on the web but when we try to open the same link inside a webview on mobile application the login is not working, sometimes it says on android logs:

```
You are running a browser with no localStorage or userData support. Logging in from one tab will not cause another tab to be logged in."
```

and sometimes it says in the logs:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://APPLICATION_URL/sockjs/657/rd1klnkr/websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established. APPLICATION_URL/login:1 http://APPLICATION_URL/login
```

please help me why is is happening?

Comment: I did not find any answer from anybody but I managed to solve my first problem by adding localstoarge support in the webview. but did not find any solution for the websocket connection error. please help me if anybody could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by adding direct way of login method in my code. I have to specify the loginStyle as direct rather than popup which is default style.

```
Meteor.loginWithGoogle({loginStyle: 'redirect'})
```